# Facing issue in handling date picker in iOS App while automation of ios application

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android, appium-ios

[image]
**Facing issue in handling date picker in iOS App while automation of ios application.**

1. Date picker is always showing current date. So, It changes everday.
2. Date format is `MMM DD, YYYY`
3. As it change on daily basis its hard to automate it with rolling measurement.

**Code**

```
List<WebElement> dateValue = driver.findElementsByClassName("XCUIElementTypePickerWheel");

for (int i = 0; i < dateValue.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(dateValue.get(i).getText());
}

dateValue.get(0).sendKeys("23");
dateValue.get(0).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);

dateValue.get(1).sendKeys("December");
dateValue.get(1).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);

dateValue.get(2).sendKeys("2000");
dateValue.get(2).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

Answer (score 0):

Appium provides `mobile:` method called `selectPickerWheelValue` that can be used for navigating a picker wheel using forward-and-back gestures:

```
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("order", "next");
params.put("offset", 0.15);
params.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement) pickerWheelElement).getId());
driver.executeScript("mobile: selectPickerWheelValue", params);
```

This approach is more robust to select values. You can check the full example [here](https://appiumpro.com/editions/59)